# What does "Needs Community Edit" do now?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

In the old days, Needs Community Edit would bounce the question into the Help and Improvement queue.

But now, that queue is retired. However, it still says "but could use some formatting":
[image: triage queue]

So what does Needs Community Edit actually do?

Comment: It seems like it goes to First Questions/Answers Queue according to the [updated Review queues map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH5x7.png) included in the [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release)

Comment: @HenryEcker Ah, that explains why some questions in FQ aren't even first answers.

Comment: I'd kinda hoped no questions in FQ were first answers :think:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/571958) on MSE:

> Questions that would have ended up in this queue [(Help & improvement)] from Triage (with a *Needs community edit* action) will now enter the **First questions queue**.

<sup>Found at the third bullet, under the first list item, under *Other changes to the Review queues* header</sup>